# Set UIControl's font to uppercase

Tags: string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uppercase

How do I set this to be uppercase?

```
- (void)drawSegmentedControl
{
    HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"]];
    segmentedControl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:16];
}
```

Comment: `HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"FIRST", @"SECOND", @"THIRD"]];`. Is that what you're wanting? I'm not quite sure I understand your question.

Comment: You can just write the titles in upper case 
or call [@"First" uppercaseString]; and so on for other titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"FIRST", @"SECOND", @"THIRD"]];
```

The font will render the character you ask it to; you have to use an uppercase letter and not a lowercase one (they are different).

If the text isn't hardcoded, convert it with `[NSString uppercaseString]` before creating the control.

Your choice of font will decide how the individual *glyphs* are rendered to the screen (are they **bold**, *italic*; comic sans or courier etc). But you can't apply CSS-style styling to render them uppercase (much as you can't do that by formation the font using a word processor's font tool.

You simply need to uppercase the string you are passing in.